# Sending a Bitmap to a wrapped c# dll in Delphi 5

Tags: c#, delphi, dll, bitmap, wrapper

I work with Delphi 5. We need to communicate with a third-party hardware using their library which does not provide COM interoperability. After a little research; I made a wrapper for the library and was able to load it and use in out software. (Thanks to other members having similar issues)

Everythings works without issues except for a single call. It receives a Bitmap and adds it to a receipt object for printing.

```
public void ReceiptAddImageLine(Bitmap imgImage)
    {
        recReceipt.addLine(new ReceiptImageLine(imgImage));
    } (C# wrapper)
```

When I call that procedure, passing a TBitmap, I get the following error while attempting to compile:

"[Error] repreceipt.pas(2461): Incompatible types: '_Bitmap' and 'TBitmap'"

Here is the actual call:

```
prPrinter.ReceiptAddImageLine(qriCode.Picture.Bitmap); (Delphi 5 call)
```

As previously stated, all other wrapped procedure calls are working without any issues. I know it's probably just a simple type conversion error but I can't seem to find what I did wrong and how to work around the issue.

I'm loading the dll as a library type.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Surely you cannot expect C# `Bitmap` to be binary compatible with Delphi `TBitmap`? You need to pass around an `HBITMAP`. On the Delphi side you use `ReleaseHandle` to get the `HBITMAP`. On the C# side it would be `Image.FromHbitmap`. For interop purposes it is `IntPtr`, as should be obvious from the signature of `Image.FromHbitmap`.

Comment: Hard to explain why I actually expected that and never saw the obvious error. It makes a lot of sense. Thanks David.